# Pick tasks from database and assign to alarm manger?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I am creating an app whose requirement is like some tasks stored in `DATABASE`. All the records are set to run on set time.

How to set alarm manager for next task to execute every time when first one is completed?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Use Android's AlarmManager to schedule an event.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/). It may help you for your requirement.